# cast one element of char array to int

Tags: c, casting, char

I have char array:

```
char c[10]="ff213";
```

and I need to cast one element of char to int. I tried this:

```
int i=atoi(c[2]);
```

But I get Runtime error. And this:

```
int i=(int)c[2];
```

But it returns 50 instead of 2.
How can I do that?

Comment: It is good to include error messages as they are, in the question.

Comment: It returns 50 instead of 2 because 50 is the ASCII value for the char "2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error you're getting is that `atoi()` expects a string (i.e. a `char*` to a null-terminated string).

Not only you're giving `atoi()` a char and not a pointer, the null-byte (`'\0'`) only exists after  the 5th char.

The easiest way of accomplishing what you're after is:

```
int i = c[2] - '0';
```

This way, the ascii code for `'2'` (50) is subtracted by the ascii code for `'0'` (48), and yield the correct answer for `i`.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but by giving atoi c[2] he is essentially de-referencing the c array. Wouldn't it be better to give atoi(&c[2])? This way it should give back i as 213.

Comment: by calling atoi(&c[2]) he'll indeed call the function with the correct  argument (i.e. pointer to null-terminated string), and get 213 back in i. the problem is that he wanted to only "cast" the 3rd char, and not the entire following string.

Answer (score 2):

Like so:

```
const int digit2 = c[2] - '0';
```

This works because C guarantees that the encodings for the decimal digits are in sequence and without any gaps.

This is not (as you can see) a "cast", it's just plain computation. If you cast the character, you get the encoding's representation as an integer, in your case 50 (hex 0x32) which is the ASCII (and UTF-8, and a bunch of other encodings) encoding of the digit 2.

Comment: unwind, you mean `c[2] - '0'`, `'\0'` is `NUL` character

Comment: @AlterMann Absolutely, that was a silly typo! Thanks!